# javascript to detect which two keyboard keys were clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a html page which is having menus on it. The menus are having a javascript.
In this javascript if keyboard key 1 is pressed then I call the link of the first menu and this was working fine but now the requirement is increased upto 17-18 menus. That is if user press 16 (i.e key 1 and then key 6) the 16th numbered menu must be displayed. I want help in identifying which two keys are pressed simultaneously.

```
if(event.keyCode==49)
            {
                self.location="pages/abc/finishgoods.jsp";

            }
            if(event.keyCode==50)
            {
                window.navigate("pages/submenu.jsp");

            }
```

Can any one please help me in detecting this. I cannot use jquery as my page is for IE 6

Comment: jQuery supports IE6

Comment: @ Aesthete. thanks. I think its having limited support and I tried for calendar(datepicker) but I am facing performance issues as I am making it for handheld device.

Comment: as you mentioned datepicker, i think you are talking about jQuery UI, which is not the same thing with jQuery

Comment: thanks Igor..do you mean I can directly use jquery in it. and it will work fine in windows handheld device. can you please share code for the same.

Comment: Cant you implenet it in a way where you can remember the last key press, so say if the first was 1 then the second was 16 then you say o its 16?

Comment: Hi Liam McCann..I want to do the same thing but as I am having a call on key 1, when the user press one the event is immedietely fired and so we cannot check for the next keypressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines (untested, but theory is here)

```
var current_keys = [], // to store keypresses
    key_timer;

// on press, store the current key and give the user a little while to press another
// on keypress {
  current_keys.push(event.keyCode);
  clearTimeout(keyTimer); // refresh the timer
  keyTimer = setTimeout(interpret_keys, 250);
// }

// they've had their chance, work out what they pressed
function interpret_keys ()
{
  var keys = -1
      key,
      i = 0;

  for (i; i < current_keys.length; i++)
  {
    key = current_keys[i] - 48; // turn 48 to 0, 49 to 1, etc
    key >= 0 && key <= 9 && keys += '' + key; // only 0-9 is valid here
  }

  keys = parseInt(keys); // make sure it's a number
  current_keys = []; // reset the tracking variable

  // keys now contains (theoretically) a number such as 1, 2, 16, etc, which can map to your selectable item
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Joe. The code is working fine.+1 from me.I was working on it since morning you cracked it for me quickly.Thanks.